# watch not catching this.value with ControllerAs Syntax

Tags: angularjs

the watch is not catching changes to `ng-model="billing.inputBoxFilter"`. Any ideas? There are no errors. Just no output from `console.log`

```
          <ng-include
            src="'billing/billing.html'"
            ng-controller="BillingCtrl as billing"></ng-include>
```

---

```
      <md-input-container flex="50">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input ng-model="billing.inputBoxFilter" type="text"
          ng-disabled="selectedItem">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="magnify"></md-icon></md-icon>
      </md-input-container>
```

---

```
angular.module('patientBilling')
  .controller('BillingCtrl', [

      this.inputBoxFilter;
      $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function() {
        return this.inputBoxFilter;
        }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
          console.log(newValue);
      }));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just  use a reference of `this`.

```
  var vm = this;

  $scope.$watch(function() {
    return vm.inputBoxFilter
  }, function(newValue, oldValue) {
    console.log(newValue);
  });
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/Hkb8He0Y3IJChA8BgQAH?p=preview)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Controller instance is available as a property on the scope when controllerAs identifier is defined, this is the reason why controllerAs syntax is used.

It is

```
$scope.$watch('billing.inputBoxFilter', function(newValue, oldValue) { ... });
```

Comment: I originally had this, but in the callback I need `this` environment for other stuff.

Comment: In this case `vm` may not be appropriate as well. It is recommended to explain the whole situation in the question in order to receive the most complete answer. For Angular 1.5 and higher the preferred way to do this is $onChanges hook, which doesn't involve $scope at all and suits current Angular trends.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a syntax issue(not error) where the callback arguments were not correct. A good example on how ControllerAs syntax breaks readability and causes excess code.

```
  $scope.$watch(angular.bind(this, function() {
    return vm.inputBoxFilter;
    }), function(newValue, oldValue) {
      console.log(newValue);
    });
```

Comment: no need to use `bind()` if you follow best practice of always storing a `this` reference and use that reference throughout